# How do I link my web pages (on usb) to my local host

Tags: php

I have a website which is currently saved on my usb and I have a form on one of the pages which I wish to link up with a database which is also on the usb (using xasmpp 1.7.4).
The problem Im having is that I'm not too sure how to connect the two up so that when you enter information into the form and click submit how to get it to be added to the table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more details and what you've tried, this is currently too vague to be answerable without guessing what your trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to have a HTML form be submitted directly to the database. You need to have an intermediary script which receives the form data from the HTTP request, processes it, and saves it to the database. Have you chosen a scripting language for this application? I can write a quick example for you in that language if you'd like.

Here's a quick PHP example which [receives POST data](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php) and [inserts it into a MySQL database](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlinsert.php).

```
<?php

/**
 * This page's URL is the "action" attribute of a form somewhere else.
 * It will receive the form data (two fields, 'username' and 'password')
 * and save it to the database.
 */

$username = addslashes($_POST['username']);
$password = addslashes($_POST['password']);

$db = mysql_connect('database_host', 'database_user', 'database_pass');
mysql_select_db('Project', $db);

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (username, password) VALUES ('$username', '$password')", $db);
mysql_close($db);

?>
```

#### Original answer

If I understood your question correctly, you have a form inside an HTML page on a USB drive that you want to submit to a page on the "localhost" domain?

Use HTML's `action` attribute. This tells the browser where to submit the data entered in the form.

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/submit">
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah, but how do I ensure that it submits it to the table user within the database Project ?

Comment: You don't submit a form to a database or a table user (whatever that's supposed to be). You submit it to a script.

Comment: You need to make a script on your localhost server that receives the form information, processes it, and saves it to the database. You can't make HTTP requests go directly to the database.

Comment: Hi, that would be great. I have been trying to use PHP (not great at this programming lark though)

Comment: I added a quick PHP example. Please follow the links I posted for some good tutorials on these topics.